# Installing wireless driver on Ubuntu 12.10 distribution

Tags: 12.10, wireless

Brand new to the linux community.

I have an hp mini 1000 that doesn't have an ethernet port. I'm transferring everything to it via a flash drive. I'm following the instructions for '[b43 - no internet access](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)' on the wiki. Here's what's going on in my [terminal](http://pastebin.com/2RrTMFGN). What would the command in step 3 be in 12.10? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Basically, you just need to follow the relevant howto section. If possible, copy/paste commands, instead of inventing your own. In the output you posted, all commands are, for some reason, heavily modified.

Comment: I installed 12.04 and the wireless automatically came up. It was amazing. thanks mikewhatever